# Contents from remote page to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay so my problem is that when I do the following:

```
<a href="playerdetails.php?player=99VY9JR8" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That prints the playerdetails.php echo but for some reason it removes my bootstrap controls. Can someone tell me why it's doing it and how to fix it? I've already tried getting the default bootstrap modal template and still it shows the `playerdetails.php` echoes but it removes all my controls for the modal.

[image: This is how it looks]

Controls I'm looking for is these:
[image: These type.]

Comment: What _"controls"_ are you talking about?

Comment: @hungerstar The X button and the title bar, the footer (not really needed) but those are the 'controls' I am looking for. So basically everything in a default modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these controls to function you need to provide the markup for them, bootstrap doesn't add them to modals automatically. If you can modify the output of `playerdetails.php`, simply add the markup there...e.g.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
</div>
```

However Bootstrap has deprecated the remote option since v3.3.0 and removed it alltogether in Bootstrap 4. Instead they recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself

If you call [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) yourself you can do something like this:

```
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- load contents here -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

define your button

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-open-dialog">Launch Demo Modal</button>
```

and bind a jQuery click event to it to load your player

```
$('.btn-open-dialog').on('click', function(){
    $('#myModal .modal-body').load('playerdetails.php?player=99VY9JR8', function(){
        /* load finished, show dialog */
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah! That's what it was thank you for your very fast and professional response.